# Element OS random automatic logout

Tags: linux, operating-system

Im trying Element os for the first time. Bevor this I used Ubuntu. Now in Element OS sometimes the System Logout me for no reason. For example if i open the File browser. Sometimes this works fine and sometimes it closes all my windows and logs me out of my account. Has anybody seen this Problem bevor ?
Im using 5.17 Hera and i updated all.

Thank you all for your Time and Help.

Comment: According to answers to this(https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/elementary-os-5-1-hera-based-ubuntu-18-04-automatic-logout-session-occasionall/24806#24806) question it might be a problem with the os itself. You could check the github page for any issues, or you could try reinstalling the os from scratch. If the problem persists i would suggest changing os.

Comment: Maybe i found a solution. I updated my drivers for my nvidia graphicscard. Since this i never saw this problem again. I hope this was the fix.